# How to redirect the homepage url to particular required url In sharepoint 2013..?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

how to do this in sharepoint 2013
if i enter this url **https://example.com/abc/sites/home.aspx** it should redirect to **https://example.com/abc/sites/home/Menu.aspx**

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the home page and insert some js code to redirect to the target page.

> Check [redirect to another page programmatically](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/sharepoint-2013-redirect-page-to-another-page/)

BR